# Срезы в Python. Не могу понять, что здесь не так

Tags: python

Не могу понять, что здесь не так.
Есть строка:

```
s = "Hello World!"
```

В ней 12 символов, индексация идёт с 0.
Чтобы получить первый индекс я пишу:

```
print(s[0])
```

По идее ведь, чтобы вывести через срез все символы в строке, я должен написать:

```
print(s[0:11])
```

Но Питон говорит нет!
Правильный ответ:

```
print(s[0:12])
```

Как так, почему? Должна быть ошибка выхода за пределы O_o

Comment: У срезов не бывает ошибок выхода за пределы. Верхняя граница среза это не индекс, а порядковый номер. Попробуйте срезом получить первый элемент (нулевой индекс)

Comment: Т.е. первая цифра индекс, а последняя порядковый номер? O_o

Comment: Можете смотреть на это как на аналог range(start, end) - первый параметр включён, последний нет.

Comment: Благодарю, господа)

Comment: В срезах можно опускать индексы. Запись вида `s[::]` вернёт всю строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что правая граница невключительно, а значит 11 отрежет на 1 символ меньше.